# How to move Camera in Rajawali Virtual Reality framework for android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, rajawali, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

This is the link of Rajawali VR example :

https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliVR

I want to add a feature that the user can move the camera around in the scene just like a FPS game such as Counter-Strike.

so,I write this code in the RajawaliVRExampleActivity's onCreate method :

```
/**this is the method*/ 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


    mRenderer = new RajawaliVRExampleRenderer(this);
    mRenderer.setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView);
    setRenderer(mRenderer);

    /**this is what I write*/
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i = 1;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRenderer.getCurrentCamera().setZ(i--);
            Log.i("i = ", ""+i);
            handler.postDelayed(this,2000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,2000);
}
```

I think it will move forward every two second after i run the program,but there's a difference between the left side and right side.

So,who can tell me how to move the camera correctly?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a proper method to achive this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and managed to overcome the issue by modifying the `RajiwaliSideBySideRenderer` class and making `mCameraLeft` and `mCameraRight` public in order to be able to modify the position of each one manually.

I'm sure there is a better solution, and as of now I'm trying to find a way to force the update of both of the cameras simultaneously when one of them is modified, but I'm still trying to figure out how.

Comment: Hi, did you find a proper method to achieve this?